# How do I go from io.ReadCloser to io.ReadSeeker?

Tags: go

I'm trying to download a file from S3 and upload that file to another bucket in S3.  Copy API won't work here because I've been told not to use it.

Getting an object from S3 has a `response.Body` that's an `io.ReadCloser` and to upload that file, the payload takes a `Body` that's an `io.ReadSeeker`.

The only way I can figure this out is by saving the `response.Body` to a file then passing that file as a `io.ReadSeeker`.  This would require writing the entire file to disk first then reading the entire file from disk which sounds pretty wrong.

What I would like to do is:

```
resp, _ := conn.GetObject(&s3.GetObjectInput{Key: "bla"})
conn.PutObject(&s3.PutObjectInput{Body: resp.Body}) // resp.Body is an io.ReadCloser and the field type expects an io.ReadSeeker
```

Question is, how do I go from an `io.ReadCloser` to an `io.ReadSeeker` in the most efficient way possible?

Comment: What specific API and functions are you using?   I can't seem to find the functions you are referring to in the Go S3 SDK.   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/s3.html

Comment: @BadZen I've added the calls that I would be using.

Comment: It's weird that you can't use the copy functions - that's what they are there for.  Maybe push back on that.   Your only other option besides writing the file to disk is going to be re-issuing the GetObject() on your `io.ReadSeeker` seek request, and setting the range field to start at the position of the seek.   It's in every way a worse solution than the already wrong write-it-to-disk, however.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

[`io.ReadSeeker`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#ReadSeeker) is the interface that groups the basic `Read()` and `Seek()` methods. The definition of the `Seek()` method:

```
Seek(offset int64, whence int) (int64, error)
```

An implementation of the `Seek()` method requires to be able to seek *anywhere* in the source, which requires *all* the source to be available or reproducible. A file is a perfect example, the file is saved permanently to your disk and any part of it can be read at any time.

`response.Body` is implemented to read from the underlying TCP connection. Reading from the underlying TCP connection gives you the data that the client at the other side sends you. The data is not cached, and the client won't send you the data again upon request. That's why `response.Body` does not implement [`io.Seeker`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Seeker) (and thus `io.ReadSeeker` either).

So in order to obtain an `io.ReadSeeker` from an `io.Reader` or `io.ReadCloser`, you need something that caches *all* the data, so that upon request it can seek to anywhere in that.

This caching mechanism may be writing it to a file as you mentioned, or you can read everything into memory, into a `[]byte` using [`ioutil.ReadAll()`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#ReadAll), and then you can use [`bytes.NewReader()`](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#NewReader) to obtain an `io.ReadSeeker` from a `[]byte`. Of course this has its limitations: all the content must fit into memory, and also you might not want to reserve that amount of memory for this file copy operation.

All in all, an implementation of `io.Seeker` or `io.ReadSeeker` requires all the source data to be available, so your best bet is writing it to a file, or for small files reading all into a `[]byte` and streaming the content of that byte slice.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, it's really helpme

Answer (score 22):

As an alternative, use [`github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/s3/s3manager.Uploader`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/s3/s3manager/#Uploader), which takes an `io.Reader` as input.

I imagine the reason that `PutObject` takes an `io.ReadSeeker` instead of an `io.Reader` is that requests to s3 need to be signed (and have a content length), but you can't generate a signature until you have all the data. The stream-y way to do this would be to buffer the input into chunks as they come in and use the multipart uploading api to upload each chunk separately. This is (I think) what `s3manager.Uploader` does behind the scenes.

Comment: This is the exact scenario that led me to this question. If you give the manager.Uploader a Reader, it will load all of the data into memory. If you can give it a reader that implements both ReaderAt and ReadSeeker, it is able to load just the data it needs to for each chunk that is uploaded.
https://aws.github.io/aws-sdk-go-v2/docs/sdk-utilities/s3/#putobjectinput-body-field-ioreadseeker-vs-ioreader